# Restoring original values using Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my application, I have to sync changes in database and an external service. If there is an error when saving to the external service, the changes done to the database should be reverted with a new update.

```
1. Get entity from database:
   var entity = context.Set<MyEntity>().Include(x => x.RelatedEntity).Find(id);

2. Perform changes to database and commit:
   entity.Name = "Changed name";
   entity.Related.Status = "Approved";
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();

3. Save to the external service:
   var response = externalService.Save(entity);

4. If there is an error, revert the changes:
   if (response.StatusCode != 200)
   {
       ???
   }
```

How could I restore the original values at step 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remember previous values from `Entry`

```cs
var entity = context.Set<MyEntity>().Include(x => x.RelatedEntity).Find(id);

entity.Name = "Changed name";
entity.Related.Status = "Approved";

// save original values
var entityOriginalValues = context.Entry(entity).OriginalValues.Clone();
var relatedOriginalValues = context.Entry(entity.Related).OriginalValues.Clone();

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var response = externalService.Save(entity);

if (response.StatusCode != 200)
{
      // revert values
      context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entityOriginalValues);
      context.Entry(entity.Related).CurrentValues.SetValues(relatedOriginalValues);
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You can do that in generic way by inspecting ChangeTracker

```cs
// save original values
var savedValues = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
   .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
   .Select(e => (Entry : e, OrinalValues : e.OriginalValues.Clone()))
   .ToList();

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var response = externalService.Save(entity);

if (response.StatusCode != 200)
{
   // reverting all modified entities
  
   foreach (var saved in savedValues)
   {
         saved.Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(saved.OrinalValues);
   }

   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Anyway this solution is not fail safe, it can be concurrent updates which may change the same data and everything will fail into collision. Also, for example, when application crashed during reverting, you will miss reverting.
Transactions can be solution but they may block other users.

Anyway, if you have a lot of such cases, better to think about implementing Saga pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a transaction to rollback the operations within in it.
(see Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions).

Example:

```
using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

// Get entity from database
var entity = context.Set<MyEntity>().Include(x => x.RelatedEntity).Find(id);

// Perform and save changes
entity.Name = "Changed name";
entity.Related.Status = "Approved";
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

// External service call
var response = externalService.Save(entity);

// Only commit the transaction when the when the external service call
// is successful. If not, the transaction will rollback when disposed.
if (response.IsSuccesStatusCode)
{
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: The transaction will not affect `externalService.Save(entity)`, that's the whole point of this question.

Comment: @GertArnold Are you sure? "If there is an error when saving to the external service, the changes done to the database should be reverted" - I don't read this as if he needs to affect `externalService.Save(entity)` in any way, rather that he needs to handle his own db in case of the external service call fails (which would cause the two to differ).

Comment: Maybe OP should decide if this pattern will do. The call to the external service may succeed without responding. It's all very brittle. If they're OK with it I won't mind removing the DV.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you wrap the whole thing in a transaction block and do commit when successful and in case of issues or exception you rollback the transaction as in :

```
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // 1. Get entity from database
        var entity = context.Set<MyEntity>().Include(x => x.RelatedEntity).Find(id);

        // 2. Perform changes to database (within transaction)
        entity.Name = "Changed name";
        entity.Related.Status = "Approved";
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Changes are pending within the transaction

        // 3. Save to the external service
        var response = externalService.Save(entity);

        if (response.StatusCode != 200)
        {
            // 4. Rollback database changes if external service call fails
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new Exception("External service save failed. Changes rolled back.");
        }

        // Commit transaction if successful
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Ensure rollback even if an exception occurs
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw; // Rethrow the exception to propagate it for handling
    }
}
```

Comment: The transaction scope will not affect `externalService.Save(entity)`, that's the whole point of this question. It's not even sure that a distributed transaction can be set up.